# Pattern in lists

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have lists of numbers, the numbers indicate a position on a circle.

The numbers can only be from 1 to 8 (like an analog clock with 8 hours).
The numbers represent a change in position of an object on the circle (8,3,1 meaning the object entered position 8 moved to 3 and then to 1).
Each list represents the positions in one trial.

I want to check if there is a similarity between trials (between lists).
It is possible that there is no similarity between them and the movement are completely random. But I think there is, according to the example the object started four trials from position 8 and it there seems to be a lot of transitions between 3 and 8.

The object is a lives honey bee who takes a drop of sugar in this positions.
The list is as long as the number of times the bee reached the positions until she took all the rewards.

I want to assess whether the movement is completely random or if there is a pattern, the information is important to me for planning a future experiment.

Example of lists:

```
{8, 3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 8, 3, 6, 6, 1}, {8, 7,5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 6, 4}, {6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7,6, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 8}, {8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 6}, {6, 3, 2, 8,4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7}, {3, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 8}, {1, 1, 7,6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 3, 8}, {8, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6}
```

Comment: Perhaps `DistanceMatrix[examples]` or `DistanceMatrix[example, DistanceFunction -> EditDistance]` might be interesting here.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to compare to random trials: `randomTrial := NestWhile[Append[#, RandomChoice[Range[8]]]&, {}, (Length[DeleteDuplicates[#]]<8)&]`.

Comment: Please take a look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SequenceAlignmentAndComparison.html to try and build features you can test your hypothesis against.

Comment: Since you are looking at random movement, should you also define your trials as `movement = Differences /@ trials;` ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, for start I will try to check LongestCommonSubsequence. If I see similar sequences repeating themselves it may be good direction.

Comment: Per @user293787 comment, this will be helpful too: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html

Comment: Not sure I understood but maybe you want the mutual information between the different trials. There is a resource function (by "wolfram summer school") [MututalInformation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MutualInformation) but I never had to use it. Maybe correlation between trials would suffice not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a starting point for checking similarity between trials.

Using `NeedlemanWunschSimilarity` we see that there are 3 clusters.

```
trials = {{8, 3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 8, 3, 6, 6, 
    1}, {8, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 3, 6, 3, 6, 4}, {6, 3, 4, 3, 1,
     2, 2, 3, 7, 6, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 8}, {8, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    3, 8, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 5, 3, 8, 4, 1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 
    6}, {6, 3, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 8, 7}, {3, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3,
     4, 2, 8}, {1, 1, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 7, 4, 1, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 
    7, 6, 5, 3, 8}, {8, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3, 2, 8, 
    5, 6}};

(* choose a distance metric *)
distanceFunction = NeedlemanWunschSimilarity;
distances = 
  DistanceMatrix[trials, DistanceFunction -> distanceFunction];

(* cluster *)
clusters = FindClusters @@
   {
    distances,
    "PerformanceGoal" -> "Quality",
    Method -> {"Agglomerate", 
      ClusterDissimilarityFunction -> "Complete"},
    DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance
    };
numberOfClusters = Length[clusters];

(* useful cluster output *)
clusterAssociation = 
  Association[Flatten[MapIndexed[(#1 -> #2[[1]]) &, clusters, {2}]]];
clusterComponents = Replace[distances, clusterAssociation, {1}];
clustersByPosition = 
  Flatten[Position[clusterComponents, #]] & /@ Range[numberOfClusters];

(* plot output *)
numberOfTrials = Length[trials];
trialsIndex = Range[numberOfTrials];
orderingIndex = Ordering[clusterComponents];
ticks = Thread[{trialsIndex, trialsIndex[[orderingIndex]]}];

plot =
  MatrixPlot[
   distances[[orderingIndex, orderingIndex]],
   FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {ticks, ticks}},
   Epilog ->
    {
     MapIndexed[
      Text[NumberForm[#1, {3, 0}], Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &,
      Reverse[distances[[orderingIndex, orderingIndex]]],
      {2}
      ]}
   ] ;

Print[clustersByPosition] (* {{1, 7}, {2, 3, 5, 6, 8}, {4}} *)
Print[plot]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,  needleman wunsch similarity allows comparison between lists of different lengths. I will definitely continue in this direction.

Comment: Nice answer. Note however that the NeedlemanWunschSimilarity is actually negative in most cases, try `Outer[NeedlemanWunschSimilarity,trials,trials,1]`. Maybe it should also be normalized by the length in some way, perhaps `Outer[NeedlemanWunschSimilarity[#1,#2] / Max[Length[#1],Length[#2]]&, trials,trials,1]`.

Comment: Good point, perhaps defining `distances = 
 Outer[NeedlemanWunschSimilarity[#1, #2]/
    Max[Length[#1], Length[#2]] &, trials, trials, 1]` would be better?

Comment: Note that the answer also omits the fact that `1` is closer to `8`